# Writing a Macro to Use the Transpose Function Repeatedly

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying move rows of values into a column in Excel.  The transpose function works well, but will only move one row at a time.  I would like to get a macro that will convert 173 rows of data across three columns into one column.  Please see example below.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Rows:

```
98,058  98,058  98,314
82,362  82,684  83,326
93,410  93,479  93,761
```

Columns:

```
98,058
98,058
98,314
82,362
82,684
83,326
93410
93479
93761
```

Comment: Is this a one-off, or something that might need to be done repeatedly with data sets of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will load the data from the CurrentRegion of A1 into an array and paste into one column, beginning in A5.

I'm assuming the data is numerical, contiguous and that this is a one-off, rather than an exercise that might have to be repeated on data sets of differing sizes.  If your data is not contiguous, or not bound by empty cells, then you can hard code the range instead.

```
Private Sub transposeRows()
Dim inputRange As Variant
Dim myArray() As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim testCell As Range

'Get the range of data to copy'
Set inputRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Resize array to fit'
ReDim myArray(inputRange.Count - 1)

'Fill up array with data'
For Each testCell In inputRange
    myArray(x) = testCell
    x = x + 1
Next testCell

'Fill destination range'
Range("A5:A" & UBound(myArray) + 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myArray)

End Sub
```